# Does "Spy Fox: Hold the Mustard" take place before or after "Spy Fox: Operation Ozone"?

Tags: spy-fox-hold-the-mustard

Does *Spy Fox: Hold the Mustard* take place before or after *Spy Fox: Operation Ozone*? I'm pretty sure that it was released between *Spy Fox in Cheese Chase* and *Spy Fox 2: Some Assembly Required* which was before *Spy Fox: Operation Ozone*.

The thing that bothers me is that the Spy M.E.S.S., which features prominently throughout *Hold the Mustard* is apparently built by Professor Quack during *Operation Ozone*.

So where does in the series does *Spy Fox: Hold the Mustard* fit chronologically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at *Spy Fox: Operation Ozone*, we can see that the ship that Professor Quack is building is called **M.E.S.S. II**

[image]

Thus we can assume that is a successor to the Spy M.E.S.S. which was used throughout *Hold the Mustard*.
[image]

And so the games most probably take place in release order, that is:

1. Spy Fox in Dry Cereal
2. Spy Fox in Cheese Chase
3. Spy Fox in Hold the Mustard
4. Spy Fox 2: Some Assembly Required
5. Spy Fox: Operation Ozone